# Why is this palindrome always results as not a palindrome?

Tags: javascript, palindrome

Every time I run this code it results to "not a palindrome" even when the input is a palindrome. Why is this happening and how do I get it to show the correct result?

```js
function palindrome(){
var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

var letterArray =[];
for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++){

 letterArray.push(input[i]);
}


var backwardsArray =[];

for(var i = input.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
 backwardsArray.push(input[i]);

}
if(letterArray === backwardsArray){
 console.log(input + " is a palidrome");
}else{
 console.log(input + " is not a palidrome");
}


console.log(letterArray);
console.log(backwardsArray);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <input id="userInput"/>
 <button id="submit" onClick="palindrome()">submit</button>
 <div id="input"></div>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not the right way to compare two arrays. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/759019

Answer (score 1):

The strict equality operator (`===`) will return true only if the two values are actually the *same*. [I would recommend reading this post to better understand how works `==` and `===`](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/javascript-equality.html).
In a nutshell, two different arrays, created separately at different times, will always be two different arrays (even if they contain the same values).

```js
var a = [];
var b = [];
var c = a;
console.log(a === b); // False.
console.log(a === c); // True.
```

You need to check if every values inside the first array corresponds to the values inside the second array.
Here is a way to do it:

```
function compareArray(array1, array2){
  return (array1.length === array2.length) && array1.every(function(element, index) {
    return element === array2[index]; 
  });
}
```

```js
function compareArray(array1, array2){
  return (array1.length === array2.length) && array1.every(function(element, index) {
    return element === array2[index]; 
  });
}

console.log(compareArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])); // True.
console.log(compareArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3])); // False.
```

**This being said**, **there is shorter and  more efficient ways to check for a palindrome**. You don't need to create a single array:

```
function isPalindrome(str){
  var n = str.length;
  // You only need to iter on half of the string.
  for(var i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
    if(str[i] !== str[n - i - 1]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```js
function isPalindrome(str){
  var n = str.length;
  for(var i = 0; i < n / 2; i++){
    if(str[i] !== str[n - i - 1]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function palindrome(){
  var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  if(isPalindrome(input)){
    console.log(input + " is a palidrome");
  }else{
    console.log(input + " is not a palidrome");
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="userInput"/>
<button id="submit" onClick="palindrome()">submit</button>
<div id="input"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because that's not how you check if arrays are equal. try this condition:

```
if(letterArray.toString() == backwardsArray.toString()) {
//is palindrome
}
else{
//not palindrome
}
```

***EDIT***

As mentioned in comment by  @Alexander O'Mara to avoid false-positives you could even do something like:

```
if(letterArray.join('') == backwardsArray.join('')) {
    //is a palin
}
else {
 //not a palin
}
```

***Note*** this will not do type checking. Refer to @Anirudh Ramanathan comment if you want to do type checking as well

Comment: Could have false-positives, better to use `.join('')`.